# How to query for CONTAINS on an index in Cassandra 2.1.5

Tags: indexing, cassandra, keyword, contains, cql3

There is a table book which has the following definition.
Book name will be stored in column name - 
attributes will be a map which will hold attributes such as authorname, yearofpublishing, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    bookid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    createdat timestamp,
    createdon timestamp,
    description text,
    attributes map<text, text>,
    name text
) CREATE INDEX bookbyname ON project (name);
```

Question - A query should be developed to run from a generic search on the UI which will supply a string. That String should query [CONTAINS] on both the attributes column and name.

For Attributes, since it was a MAP, it supports CONTAINS keyword. However, how to do a CONTAINS query on index? In this case, bookbyname (name) field.

Comment: Why not using a simple equals operator for name? `where name = '...'`?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing. But if I have to support a wildcard search such as "Project a".. I need to retrieve all the projects that contains Project a.. So I would need to use CONTAINS then

Comment: I also wanted to point out that it looks like your `name` column shares the same cardinality as `bookid`.  Secondary indexes on high-cardinality columns are not going to perform well.  If you really need to query by book name, you should consider building a `bookbyname` query table.  That won't solve your main problem here, but it'll save you from some performance headaches later on.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra does not support matching partial strings using the CONTAINS or LIKE operator. You should look into solutions such as [Stargate](http://tuplejump.github.io/stargate/) or [DSE](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html) that provide search functionality on top of Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I will look at Stargate and check if it provides options for CONTAINS or LIKE operator.